# How to make echo interpret backslash escapes and not print a trailing newline?

Tags: bash, echo

I would like to use `echo` in bash to print out a string of characters followed by only a carriage return. I've looked through the man page and have found that `echo -e` will make `echo` interpret backslash escape characters. Using that I can say `echo -e 'hello\r'` and it will print like this

```
$>echo -e 'hello\r'
 hello
$>
```

So it looks like it  handled the carriage return properly. I also found `echo -n` in the man page will stop `echo` from inserting a newline character and it looks like it works when I do this

```
$>echo -n 'hello\r'
 hello\r$>
```

The problem I'm having is in combining both `-e` and `-n`. I've tried each of `echo -e -n 'hello\r'`, `echo -n -e 'hello\r'`, `echo -en 'hello\r'`, and `echo -ne 'hello\r'` and nothing gets printed like so:

```
$>echo -ne 'hello\r'
$>
```

Is there something I'm missing here or can the `-e` and `-n` options not be used together?

Comment: `$> echo -ne 'hello\r'`

will leave the cursor at the start of the line containing the 'hello'.  So if your prompt is longer than the `$>` you have here, it will overwrite the hello.

Comment: “nothing gets printed”? Surely you'd get ‘`$>llo`’ because your 2-character prompt-string would not completely overwrite the 5 characters of ‘hello’. Note that ‘carriage return’ isn't the same as ‘new line’ (see `man ascii`). So it seems that you've successfully replaced new line with carriage return yet you're surprised that carriage return doesn't behave like new line. Why did you want to do this? I'm curious. Also, without the quotes the shell interprets the backslash as an escape character so `\r` just becomes `r`. That means your first command actually prints ‘`hellor`’ not ‘`hello`’.

Comment: Did you run these commands on the same shell? `echo -n hello\r` should have outputted exactly the same as `echo -ne hello\r`; they both print ‘`hellor`’ (without a new line, so the prompt appears as ‘`hellor$>`’). The `-e` is irrelevant here because there's no backslash escape after the shell has stripped it. `echo -ne 'hello\r'` or `echo -ne hello\\r` both pass the argument ‘`hello\r`’ to `echo`.

Comment: At the time of this writing, only 1 of your 4 examples seems to have the correct result (though I'm not sure about the leading space), but I don't think that I can edit this question to correct the examples without loosing the original meaning. :-/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it's working, you're just not seeing it. This is your command:

```
$> echo -ne 'hello\r'
```

Because of the carriage return (`\r`), that will leave the cursor at the start of the same line on the terminal where it wrote the `hello` - which means that's where the next thing output to the terminal will be written. So if your actual prompt is longer than the `$>` you show here, it will overwrite the `hello` completely.

This sequence will let you see what's actually happening:

```
echo -ne 'hello\r'; sleep 5; echo 'good-bye'
```

But for better portability to other shells, I would avoid using options on `echo` like that. Those are purely bashisms, not supported by the POSIX standard. The `printf` builtin, however, is specified by POSIX. So if you want to display strings with no newline and parsing of backslash sequences, you can just use it:

```
printf '%s\r' 'hello'
```

Answer (score 11):

There are numerous different implementations of the `echo` command.  There's one built into most shells (with different behavior for each), and the behavior of `/bin/echo` varies considerably from one system to another.

Rather than `echo`, use `printf`.  It's built into bash as well as being available as an external command, and its behavior is much more consistent across implementations.  (The major variation is that the GNU coreutils `printf` recognizes `--help` and `--version` options.)

Just use:

```
printf 'hello\r'
```

Comment: +1 `echo` is fine for printing single lines, but as soon as you use any special options or escapes it gets unreliable and unportable.  `printf` is much better for anything like this.

Comment: The question is tagged as bash-specific, though.  Seems likely the OP doesn't need portability for their use case.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like you to introduce you to [printf](http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html).

OP, meet `printf`. `printf`. This is the OP...

Whenever you are trying to do anything *unusual* with output in BASH, you should switch to `printf`. In fact, I use `printf` all the time, so my scripts will run under both BASH and Kornshell.

Although BASH and Kornshell are 99% the same, the `echo` command is different. In Kornshell, it's deprecated, and you're supposed to use the builtin `print`. However, there's no `print` in BASH. Using `printf` solves the problem because it works (sort of) the same in both shells.

Since `printf` doesn't automatically end each line with a `\n`, you don't have to worry about how to prevent the `\n` from being appended. Heck, if you want a `\n`, you have to put it yourself. In your case:

```
printf `hello\r`
```

However, for safety reasons, you should really do this:

```
printf '%s\r' 'hello'
```

This is a habit I've gotten into when I'm using `printf`. Imagine if I want to print out `$FOO`, and I do this:

```
printf "$FOO\n"
```

That will normally work, but what if `$FOO` has a dash at the beginning, or has a `%` sign in it. The above won't do what I want to do. However, if I do this:

```
printf '%s\n' "$FOO"
```

This will print out `$FOO` no matter what `$FOO` has in it.

Comment: FYI, your first `printf` example has backticks instead of apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX 7 [says it is not possible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_05):

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash character, the results are implementation-defined.

On Ubuntu 12.04 for example:

- Bash's built-in echo `echo -e '\n'` interprets the newline, `echo '\n'` does not.
- `/bin/sh`'s built-in `echo` does not have the `-e` option, and interprets the newline even without it. This can byte when writing `Makefile`s, which use `/bin/sh` by default.

POSIX 7 solution: `printf` as the others mentioned.

Comment: That's POSIX; OP asked about bash specifically. And the behavior of `echo` *in bash* is well-defined and documented, including the `-e` and `-n` options and the treatment of backslashes.

Comment: @Mark Reed I never claimed otherwise. But many Googlers who come here may be interested in the POSIX behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting. It's the wave of the future. Always quote.

```
echo -ne 'hello\r'
```

Use double quotes if you put a variable inside that you want expanded.

Comment: Quoting doesn't work either. When I use quotes nothing gets printed. I'll update the question for that

Comment: @swatso33: It works for me. What do you get when you try: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`

Comment: Its version `4.2.24(2)-release`. Running on arch linux if it makes a difference. Must just be my version then. Which version do you have it working on?

Comment: @swatso33: Bash 2.05b.0(2)-release, 3.2.51(2)-release, 4.0.33(1)-release, 4.1.9(3)-release and 4.2.0(1)-release. Plus ksh 93t+, pdksh v5.2.14 99/07/13.2, mksh KSH R39 2009/08/01 Debian 39.1-3 and zsh 4.3.10. Also, fish 1.23.1 and tcsh 6.14.00 (tcsh doesn't need and can't use `-e` but it interprets escapes by default).