# how to tab separate variables in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have 2 variable :$table and $i

```
table=test
i=1
```

when i try to separate these two variables with tab with the below command:

```
echo "$table\t$i\tSuccess" > success.txt
```

The output is

```
 test\ti
```

The desired output is

```
test    1
```

Appreciate valuable suggestions.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576571/how-to-make-echo-interpret-backslash-escapes-and-not-print-a-trailing-newline

Comment: Thanks for the sharing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
printf "%s\t%s\tSuccess\n" "$table" "$i" > success.txt
```

or `echo -e` (the `-e` flag enables interpretation of the backslash-escaped characters):

```
 echo -e "$table\t$i\tSuccess" > success.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a tab in Bash as $'\t'.

What I do in my scripts is create a constant. The tab itself is not special: once you have it in a variable, you can use it the normal way.

```
readonly tab=$'\t'
echo "$table$tab$i${tab}Success" > success.txt
```